# How to wait for complete return value in dispatch with redux-saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to get `myLocation`(redux state) variable which is used in next dispatch `GET_POSTS_REQUEST`. But when i tried to put `await` to get fully return value, it shows error.

index.js

```
const testFunc = () => {
const { myLocation} = useSelector(state => state.user);
                dispatch({
                    type: MY_LOCATION_REQUEST,
                    data: {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        long: position.coords.longitude,
                    },
                });
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_POSTS_REQUEST,
                    data: {
                        dong: myLocation.dong,
                    },
                });
};
```

sagas/location.js

```
function getLocationAPI(locationInfo) {
    return axios.post('/location', locationInfo ,{withCredentials: true});
}

function* getLocation(action) {
    try {
        const result = yield call(getLocationAPI, action.data);
        yield put({
            type: GET_LOCATION_SUCCESS,
            data: result.data,
        });
    } catch (e) {
        yield put({
            type: GET_LOCATION_FAILURE,
            error: e,
        });
    }
}

function* watchGetLocation() {
    yield takeLatest(GET_LOCATION_REQUEST, getLocation);
}

export default function* locationSaga() {
    yield all([
        fork(watchGetLocation),
    ]);
}
```

I have to use `myLocation` for next dispatch action in `index.js`. But, when i tried to put `async/await` to my `dispatch`, it didn't work. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**put** method kinda dispatches too, for example this part

```js
yield put({
    type: GET_LOCATION_SUCCESS,
    data: result.data,
});
```

you can always see as

```js
dispatch({
    type: GET_LOCATION_SUCCESS,
    data: result.data,
});
```

So you have to "catch" this with reducer, for example

```js
function yourReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_LOCATION_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        user: Object.assign({},
          state.user,
          {
            myLocation: action.data
          }
        ]
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

And this will update your state with data returned from api call